# read a specif value in a xml file using automation anywhere

Tags: xml, automationanywhere

I can't find the node that I want

I want to extract the value in CNPJ.

Im using the get single node and Im trying to use this xpath: /nfeProc/NFe/infNFe/emit/CNPJ, but there's a error: no nodes found in xpath

does anyone know what i can do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="4.00">


-<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">


-<infNFe versao="4.00" Id="NFe31200947960950091330550090003952391015159249">


-<ide>

<cUF>31</cUF>

<cNF>01515924</cNF>

<natOp>VENDA MERCADORIA ADQUIR/RECEB TERCEIROS TP:51</natOp>

<mod>55</mod>

<serie>9</serie>

<nNF>395239</nNF>

<dhEmi>2020-09-28T07:31:11-03:00</dhEmi>

<dhSaiEnt>2020-09-28T07:32:09-03:00</dhSaiEnt>

<tpNF>1</tpNF>

<idDest>2</idDest>

<cMunFG>3118601</cMunFG>

<tpImp>1</tpImp>

<tpEmis>1</tpEmis>

<cDV>9</cDV>

<tpAmb>1</tpAmb>

<finNFe>1</finNFe>

<indFinal>1</indFinal>

<indPres>2</indPres>

<procEmi>0</procEmi>

<verProc>3.76.0</verProc>

</ide>


-<emit>

**<CNPJ>47960950091330</CNPJ>**

<xNome>MAGAZINE LUIZA S/A</xNome>

<xFant>CD505</xFant>


-<enderEmit>

<xLgr>WILSON TAVARES RIBEIRO</xLgr>

<nro>1400</nro>

<xBairro>CHACARAS REUNIDAS SA</xBairro>

<cMun>3118601</cMun>

<xMun>CONTAGEM</xMun>

<UF>MG</UF>

<CEP>32183680</CEP>

<cPais>1058</cPais>

<xPais>BRASIL</xPais>

</enderEmit>

<IE>0402992109650</IE>

<IEST>813013975111</IEST>

<CRT>3</CRT>

</emit>


-<dest>

<CPF>40526495839</CPF>

<xNome>IVAN SILVA COSTA</xNome>


-<enderDest>

<xLgr>DAS PAINEIRAS JD PINHEIROS</xLgr>

<nro>206</nro>

<xBairro>ALVARENGA</xBairro>

<cMun>3548708</cMun>

<xMun>SAO BERNARDO DO CAMPO</xMun>

<UF>SP</UF>

<CEP>09854700</CEP>

<cPais>1058</cPais>

<xPais>BRASIL</xPais>

<fone>11949172578</fone>

</enderDest>

<indIEDest>9</indIEDest>

</dest>


-<entrega>

<CPF>40526495839</CPF>

<xLgr>DAS PAINEIRAS JD PINHEIROS</xLgr>

<nro>206</nro>

<xBairro>ALVARENGA</xBairro>

<cMun>3548708</cMun>

<xMun>SAO BERNARDO DO CAMPO</xMun>

<UF>SP</UF>

</entrega>


-<det nItem="1">


-<prod>

<cProd>6220204</cProd>

<cEAN>4549292076271</cEAN>

<xProd>MULT.CANON MEGA TANK G4100 C/ADF E WI-FI PRETO NA</xProd>

<NCM>84433111</NCM>

<CEST>2101600</CEST>

<CFOP>6108</CFOP>

<uCom>PC</uCom>

<qCom>1.0000</qCom>

<vUnCom>854.0500000000</vUnCom>

<vProd>854.05</vProd>

<cEANTrib>4549292076271</cEANTrib>

<uTrib>PC</uTrib>

<qTrib>1.0000</qTrib>

<vUnTrib>854.0500000000</vUnTrib>

<indTot>1</indTot>

</prod>


-<imposto>


-<ICMS>


-<ICMS00>

<orig>2</orig>

<CST>00</CST>

<modBC>3</modBC>

<vBC>854.05</vBC>

<pICMS>4.0000</pICMS>

<vICMS>34.16</vICMS>

</ICMS00>

</ICMS>


-<PIS>


-<PISNT>

<CST>07</CST>

</PISNT>

</PIS>


-<COFINS>


-<COFINSNT>

<CST>07</CST>

</COFINSNT>

</COFINS>


-<ICMSUFDest>

<vBCUFDest>854.05</vBCUFDest>

<vBCFCPUFDest>854.05</vBCFCPUFDest>

<pFCPUFDest>0.0000</pFCPUFDest>

<pICMSUFDest>18.0000</pICMSUFDest>

<pICMSInter>4.00</pICMSInter>

<pICMSInterPart>100.0000</pICMSInterPart>

<vFCPUFDest>0.00</vFCPUFDest>

<vICMSUFDest>119.57</vICMSUFDest>

<vICMSUFRemet>0.00</vICMSUFRemet>

</ICMSUFDest>

</imposto>

</det>


-<total>


-<ICMSTot>

<vBC>854.05</vBC>

<vICMS>34.16</vICMS>

<vICMSDeson>0.00</vICMSDeson>

<vFCPUFDest>0.00</vFCPUFDest>

<vICMSUFDest>119.57</vICMSUFDest>

<vFCP>0.00</vFCP>

<vBCST>0.00</vBCST>

<vST>0.00</vST>

<vFCPST>0.00</vFCPST>

<vFCPSTRet>0.00</vFCPSTRet>

<vProd>854.05</vProd>

<vFrete>0.00</vFrete>

<vSeg>0.00</vSeg>

<vDesc>0.00</vDesc>

<vII>0.00</vII>

<vIPI>0.00</vIPI>

<vIPIDevol>0.00</vIPIDevol>

<vPIS>0.00</vPIS>

<vCOFINS>0.00</vCOFINS>

<vOutro>0.00</vOutro>

<vNF>854.05</vNF>

</ICMSTot>

</total>


-<transp>

<modFrete>0</modFrete>


-<vol>

<qVol>1</qVol>

<esp>VOLUMES</esp>

<pesoL>9.550</pesoL>

<pesoB>9.550</pesoB>

</vol>

</transp>


-<pag>


-<detPag>

<indPag>1</indPag>

<tPag>03</tPag>

<vPag>854.05</vPag>


-<card>

<tpIntegra>1</tpIntegra>

<CNPJ>01425787000104</CNPJ>

<tBand>02</tBand>

<cAut>253889493</cAut>

</card>

</detPag>

</pag>


-<infAdic>

<infAdFisco>#</infAdFisco>

<infCpl>Val Aprox Tributos R$409,52(47,95%) Fonte:IBPT FEDERAIS 29,95%,ESTADUAIS 18,00%,MUNICIPAIS 0%NUM. PEDIDO:608315508 / CODCLI:53286139 / LOTE:770463 / CODVENDR:6001 / OBS.PED:REF.: (11 ) 949172578 - PONTO REFERENCIA = SAIDA KM23 DA RODOVIA DOS IMIGRANTES / CELULAR:11-49172578 / MODAL: COU / Valores totais do ICMS Interestadual: DIFAL da UF destino R$ 119,57 + FCP R$ 0,00 DIFAL da UF Origem R$ 0,00</infCpl>


-<obsCont xCampo="CODFIL,TPNOTA">

<xTexto>505,51</xTexto>

</obsCont>

</infAdic>

</infNFe>


-<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">


-<SignedInfo>

<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>

<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>


-<Reference URI="#NFe31200947960950091330550090003952391015159249">


-<Transforms>

<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>

<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>

</Transforms>

<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>

<DigestValue>ZfQ30oQGXZlvjXDOQvuY06X8yKs=</DigestValue>

</Reference>

</SignedInfo>

<SignatureValue>JiGRVm98/xv00zjU3EX2SktF92roXWAfXOw6g0+n9lFfm3APsl4Ygfvl963FDJZ/bjJ7Pr1Ys3M8gvPCGfiAIAhGQjvaXzU4JhgFpdxjm7RTz7yq/KXJjNHnnXgdbWYmKLkahTosP8ObDjL1S/FLu7J4t3W6llzz0u+TqOS96ig=</SignatureValue>


-<KeyInfo>


-<X509Data>

<X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>

</X509Data>

</KeyInfo>

</Signature>

</NFe>


-<protNFe versao="4.00">


-<infProt>

<tpAmb>1</tpAmb>

<verAplic>3.76.0</verAplic>

<chNFe>31200947960950091330550090003952391015159249</chNFe>

<dhRecbto>2020-09-28T07:31:12-03:00</dhRecbto>

<nProt>131203837462261</nProt>

<digVal>b+UQVgLSB8oxDFM9m3mgqXJMRFE=</digVal>

<cStat>100</cStat>

<xMotivo>Autorizado o uso da NF-e</xMotivo>

</infProt>

</protNFe>

</nfeProc>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took the xml you have and I used vscode to format it and to test your xpath query.
Everything worked fine, I think you might have an issue with the format or with the approach you are using to run the query, not the query itself.

```html
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="4.00">
  <NFe>
      -
    <infNFe versao="4.00" Id="NFe31200947960950091330550090003952391015159249">
         -
      <ide>
        <cUF>31</cUF>
        <cNF>01515924</cNF>
        <natOp>VENDA MERCADORIA ADQUIR/RECEB TERCEIROS TP:51</natOp>
        <mod>55</mod>
        <serie>9</serie>
        <nNF>395239</nNF>
        <dhEmi>2020-09-28T07:31:11-03:00</dhEmi>
        <dhSaiEnt>2020-09-28T07:32:09-03:00</dhSaiEnt>
        <tpNF>1</tpNF>
        <idDest>2</idDest>
        <cMunFG>3118601</cMunFG>
        <tpImp>1</tpImp>
        <tpEmis>1</tpEmis>
        <cDV>9</cDV>
        <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
        <finNFe>1</finNFe>
        <indFinal>1</indFinal>
        <indPres>2</indPres>
        <procEmi>0</procEmi>
        <verProc>3.76.0</verProc>
      </ide>
         -
      <emit>
            **
        <CNPJ>47960950091330</CNPJ>
            **
        <xNome>MAGAZINE LUIZA S/A</xNome>
        <xFant>CD505</xFant>
            -
        <enderEmit>
          <xLgr>WILSON TAVARES RIBEIRO</xLgr>
          <nro>1400</nro>
          <xBairro>CHACARAS REUNIDAS SA</xBairro>
          <cMun>3118601</cMun>
          <xMun>CONTAGEM</xMun>
          <UF>MG</UF>
          <CEP>32183680</CEP>
          <cPais>1058</cPais>
          <xPais>BRASIL</xPais>
        </enderEmit>
        <IE>0402992109650</IE>
        <IEST>813013975111</IEST>
        <CRT>3</CRT>
      </emit>
         -
      <dest>
        <CPF>40526495839</CPF>
        <xNome>IVAN SILVA COSTA</xNome>
            -
        <enderDest>
          <xLgr>DAS PAINEIRAS JD PINHEIROS</xLgr>
          <nro>206</nro>
          <xBairro>ALVARENGA</xBairro>
          <cMun>3548708</cMun>
          <xMun>SAO BERNARDO DO CAMPO</xMun>
          <UF>SP</UF>
          <CEP>09854700</CEP>
          <cPais>1058</cPais>
          <xPais>BRASIL</xPais>
          <fone>11949172578</fone>
        </enderDest>
        <indIEDest>9</indIEDest>
      </dest>
         -
      <entrega>
        <CPF>40526495839</CPF>
        <xLgr>DAS PAINEIRAS JD PINHEIROS</xLgr>
        <nro>206</nro>
        <xBairro>ALVARENGA</xBairro>
        <cMun>3548708</cMun>
        <xMun>SAO BERNARDO DO CAMPO</xMun>
        <UF>SP</UF>
      </entrega>
         -
      <det nItem="1">
            -
        <prod>
          <cProd>6220204</cProd>
          <cEAN>4549292076271</cEAN>
          <xProd>MULT.CANON MEGA TANK G4100 C/ADF E WI-FI PRETO NA</xProd>
          <NCM>84433111</NCM>
          <CEST>2101600</CEST>
          <CFOP>6108</CFOP>
          <uCom>PC</uCom>
          <qCom>1.0000</qCom>
          <vUnCom>854.0500000000</vUnCom>
          <vProd>854.05</vProd>
          <cEANTrib>4549292076271</cEANTrib>
          <uTrib>PC</uTrib>
          <qTrib>1.0000</qTrib>
          <vUnTrib>854.0500000000</vUnTrib>
          <indTot>1</indTot>
        </prod>
            -
        <imposto>
               -
          <ICMS>
                  -
            <ICMS00>
              <orig>2</orig>
              <CST>00</CST>
              <modBC>3</modBC>
              <vBC>854.05</vBC>
              <pICMS>4.0000</pICMS>
              <vICMS>34.16</vICMS>
            </ICMS00>
          </ICMS>
               -
          <PIS>
                  -
            <PISNT>
              <CST>07</CST>
            </PISNT>
          </PIS>
               -
          <COFINS>
                  -
            <COFINSNT>
              <CST>07</CST>
            </COFINSNT>
          </COFINS>
               -
          <ICMSUFDest>
            <vBCUFDest>854.05</vBCUFDest>
            <vBCFCPUFDest>854.05</vBCFCPUFDest>
            <pFCPUFDest>0.0000</pFCPUFDest>
            <pICMSUFDest>18.0000</pICMSUFDest>
            <pICMSInter>4.00</pICMSInter>
            <pICMSInterPart>100.0000</pICMSInterPart>
            <vFCPUFDest>0.00</vFCPUFDest>
            <vICMSUFDest>119.57</vICMSUFDest>
            <vICMSUFRemet>0.00</vICMSUFRemet>
          </ICMSUFDest>
        </imposto>
      </det>
         -
      <total>
            -
        <ICMSTot>
          <vBC>854.05</vBC>
          <vICMS>34.16</vICMS>
          <vICMSDeson>0.00</vICMSDeson>
          <vFCPUFDest>0.00</vFCPUFDest>
          <vICMSUFDest>119.57</vICMSUFDest>
          <vFCP>0.00</vFCP>
          <vBCST>0.00</vBCST>
          <vST>0.00</vST>
          <vFCPST>0.00</vFCPST>
          <vFCPSTRet>0.00</vFCPSTRet>
          <vProd>854.05</vProd>
          <vFrete>0.00</vFrete>
          <vSeg>0.00</vSeg>
          <vDesc>0.00</vDesc>
          <vII>0.00</vII>
          <vIPI>0.00</vIPI>
          <vIPIDevol>0.00</vIPIDevol>
          <vPIS>0.00</vPIS>
          <vCOFINS>0.00</vCOFINS>
          <vOutro>0.00</vOutro>
          <vNF>854.05</vNF>
        </ICMSTot>
      </total>
         -
      <transp>
        <modFrete>0</modFrete>
            -
        <vol>
          <qVol>1</qVol>
          <esp>VOLUMES</esp>
          <pesoL>9.550</pesoL>
          <pesoB>9.550</pesoB>
        </vol>
      </transp>
         -
      <pag>
            -
        <detPag>
          <indPag>1</indPag>
          <tPag>03</tPag>
          <vPag>854.05</vPag>
               -
          <card>
            <tpIntegra>1</tpIntegra>
            <CNPJ>01425787000104</CNPJ>
            <tBand>02</tBand>
            <cAut>253889493</cAut>
          </card>
        </detPag>
      </pag>
         -
      <infAdic>
        <infAdFisco>#</infAdFisco>
        <infCpl>Val Aprox Tributos R$409,52(47,95%) Fonte:IBPT FEDERAIS 29,95%,ESTADUAIS 18,00%,MUNICIPAIS 0%NUM. PEDIDO:608315508 / CODCLI:53286139 / LOTE:770463 / CODVENDR:6001 / OBS.PED:REF.: (11 ) 949172578 - PONTO REFERENCIA = SAIDA KM23 DA RODOVIA DOS IMIGRANTES / CELULAR:11-49172578 / MODAL: COU / Valores totais do ICMS Interestadual: DIFAL da UF destino R$ 119,57 + FCP R$ 0,00 DIFAL da UF Origem R$ 0,00</infCpl>
            -
        <obsCont xCampo="CODFIL,TPNOTA">
          <xTexto>505,51</xTexto>
        </obsCont>
      </infAdic>
    </infNFe>
      -
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
         -
      <SignedInfo>
        <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
        <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            -
        <Reference URI="#NFe31200947960950091330550090003952391015159249">
               -
          <Transforms>
            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
          </Transforms>
          <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
          <DigestValue>ZfQ30oQGXZlvjXDOQvuY06X8yKs=</DigestValue>
        </Reference>
      </SignedInfo>
      <SignatureValue>JiGRVm98/xv00zjU3EX2SktF92roXWAfXOw6g0+n9lFfm3APsl4Ygfvl963FDJZ/bjJ7Pr1Ys3M8gvPCGfiAIAhGQjvaXzU4JhgFpdxjm7RTz7yq/KXJjNHnnXgdbWYmKLkahTosP8ObDjL1S/FLu7J4t3W6llzz0u+TqOS96ig=</SignatureValue>
         -
      <KeyInfo>
            -
        <X509Data>
          <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
        </X509Data>
      </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
  </NFe>
   -
  <protNFe versao="4.00">
      -
    <infProt>
      <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
      <verAplic>3.76.0</verAplic>
      <chNFe>31200947960950091330550090003952391015159249</chNFe>
      <dhRecbto>2020-09-28T07:31:12-03:00</dhRecbto>
      <nProt>131203837462261</nProt>
      <digVal>b+UQVgLSB8oxDFM9m3mgqXJMRFE=</digVal>
      <cStat>100</cStat>
      <xMotivo>Autorizado o uso da NF-e</xMotivo>
    </infProt>
  </protNFe>
</nfeProc>
```

`/nfeProc/NFe/infNFe/emit/CNPJ`

My result:

```
XPath Query: /nfeProc/NFe/infNFe/emit/CNPJ

[Line 31] CNPJ: 47960950091330
```

Here are some of the plugins I used:
[image: vscode xml plugins]